# update file content with placehodler

Tags: linux, shell, sed, makefile

I’ve the following yaml file, in which I want to substitute `%IMG_NAME%` with a shell variable which I have already defined, e.g. `$IMG_NAME`.

This is the input file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: %IMG_NAME%. //this the value to update
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 50Mi
            requests:
              memory: 25Mi
```

I try to do the following which doesn’t work, any idea ?

```
sed -e ’s,myimage,’$IMG_NAME',g' < deployment.yaml
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. The `sed` prints the `deployment.yaml` to `stdout` and doesn't do anything else. The `myimage` doesn't appear in `deployment.yaml` so isn't change anything (do you want replace `%IMG_NAME%`?).

Comment: @uzsolt - yes exactly I want to replace the image name with `myimage` value

Comment: @RaynD, are you **really** trying to use **right single quotation marks (`’`)** instead of single quotes `'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue why you write `update-dep:` in your attemp. What is that?

Anyway, maybe you just want to do this:

```
sed 's/%IMG_NAME%/'"$IMG_NAME"'/g' deployment.yaml
```

where

- double quoting `$IMG_NAME` is just a good habit,
- `-e` is not necessary,
- using `,` instead of `/` is unnecessary too, as pointed out on a comment

Not specific to `sed`, it is very important to know the following:

- the symbol `'` is a **single quote**, not the right single quotation mark that you put in your question (`’`).
- if you have an actual `file` you want to pass to a unix `program` (e.g. `sed`, `awk`, and many others) you don't need to pass it like this, `program < file`, becuase many of these programs accept a file name as a command line argument, so you can do `program file`. Doing so, the `program` is aware of the file name (it isn't when you do `program < file`) and it is also aware it is a file in the first place (after `<` you could put something which is not a file). If the `program` is not aware it's working on a file (or it's not aware of what the filename is), options like `sed`'s `-i` option cannot be used, because the program has no clue where it should overwrite.

Comment: Any special reason for using commas (,) instead of slashes (/) in the substitution?

Comment: @CRM no, but the OP seems to like it. But yeah, maybe since I specified `-e` is not necessary, I can also add this.

Comment: Thanks, this works. on question how it's suggested to replace /override the file with the new value?

Comment: If you really want to do it, you can use `sed`'s `-i` option, or `-i.bkp` to create a backup file with `.bkp` appended to its filename. But this is something you should not do before you're really sure the command works.

Comment: I tried it, and I got error : `sed -i 's/%IMG_NAME%/'"MG_NAME2"'/g' < deployment.yaml
sed: -i may not be used with stdin
make: *** [update-dep] Error 1`

Comment: @RaynD, that's because you're providing the input through `<`. I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: I tried it : `sed 's/%IMG_NAME%/'"$IMG_NAME"'/g' deployment.yaml` , I saw that the output was changed with the value, however the file remain the same , doesnt changed

Comment: if you have an idea how to solve it, please let me know :) I need that the new output will override the file content

Comment: @RaynD, if you execute `sed 'blablabla' input_file` you get the output on screen. If you want to overwrite the input file, you have to use the `-i` option, e.g. `sed -i 'blablabla' input_file`. If I can add a side comment, I suggest that you consider spending some time to understand how the linux shell works (being it `bash` or any other), there are things that can be disastrous if you ignore them E.g. you could attempt something like `sed 'command' input_file > input_file` to emulate the `-i` option, but you would have **lost all the content of `input_file`**.

Comment: yea, indeed, when you are doing something like `sed  's/%IMG_NAME%/'"$IMG_NAME222"'/g' deployment.yaml > deployment.yaml` it's deleted the file, is there any trick just to override it with all the old and the new updated data? just if you have any idea, thanks anyway!